# How to test the influence of a feature on conversion?

Tags: statistics

I have a user journey where I have data of the format:

> userID, did_interact_with_feature(0/1), did_convert(0/1)

I want to verify the hypothesis that **if a user is engaging with the feature, he's more likely to get converted**.

Now I can get the % of user who engaged in feature and then got converted. But I seem to have hit a mental block here.

I was leaning toward a z-test, but could not formulate the problem.

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskStatistics/comments/9wwuub/how_do_i_measure_identify_that_the_change_in/e9ohi8m) post, I was able to test this.
The test we need is a Chi-square test for approx results and Fischer Test for exact variables.

Given, the variables I had were categoric *(engaged:yes/no and converted:yes no)* in nature, the base assumption was true.

Now, First I created contingency table for each of those engaged and converted with reference from [here](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/chi_square/contingency.html).

There after, calculated the expected value for each of the cells in table.
Injected the formula and voila, I had the chi-square vale. Further compared with chi-square value table to get the p-value.

This resulted in testing whether the variables are independent or not.

This is what the end results look like:
[image]

Reference: https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/chisquare2/Default2.aspx